# Adding multiple filters to a map created using folium

Tags: python, folium

I have a data set that contains the gps data of 5 vehicles along with the dates, now i was able to create a featuregroup of 5 vehicles and able to map them on a single date. I'm using folium, Now i want to include a filter that gives the user an option to tick mark the date along with the vehicle to plot its locations on the map.

Any help or direction to solve this problem will be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only thing I'm aware of that would be close to what you're describing is using folium's LayerControl.  But you would need to have a layer for each date and each truck.  Maybe you could do a layer for each date and then popups for vehicle identification?

Comment: yes i can do that, but if i did so then there will be data collision as in a given date all the vehicles are using the same start and end points. I already made a layer for each vehicle on a single day giving the user the option of choosing the vehicle, now i'm struck at applying it for multiple dates and giving a option for the user to select a specific vehicle on that specific date rather than all the vehicles being mapped on a selected date.

Comment: Gotcha, folium's MarkerClusters can maybe help with the collisions you mentioned.    Best of luck